# how to solve Deprecated error in moodle project?

Tags: php, apache, moodle

`Deprecated: Return type of moodle_recordset::rewind() should either be compatible with Iterator::rewind(): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/moodle/lib/dml/moodle_recordset.php on line 61`

I have try to downgrade the php version from 8.0 to 7.4 but still errors appear

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning that there is a feature being used which will no longer work in a future version of PHP. You can configure PHP to log such things to a file instead of showing them on screen. If this isn't your code then you could check with the vendor/developer of the code if there are any plans to update their code to remove their use of deprecated code at some point. But it's possibly not an urgent problem.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Moodle are you using?

Looks like this was fixed in Moodle version 3.11.8 and 4.0.2 in July

https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-70745

You probably need to upgrade Moodle to be compatible with PHP 8